# mongo go if [] is empty deem it as false

Tags: mongodb, go, mongo-go

Currently if a user has a subscriptions object but it is empty i.e [] then it will not be deemed as subscriptions = false.

```
// hasActiveSubscriptions
hasSubscriptions := c.QueryParam("hasSubscriptions")
if hasSubscriptions != "" {

    hasSubscriptions = strings.ToUpper(hasSubscriptions)
    if hasSubscriptions != "TRUE" && hasSubscriptions != "FALSE" {
        fmt.Println("hasSubscriptions query param is an invalid value")
    }
    res, err := strconv.ParseBool(hasSubscriptions)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
            if res {
        pipeline = append(pipeline, bson.M{
            "$match": bson.M{
                "subscriptions": bson.M{"$ne": nil},
            },
        })
    } else {
        pipeline = append(pipeline, bson.M{
            "$match": bson.M{"subscriptions": nil},
        })
    }

}
```

This is where the call happens.
Currently it returns no objects if I append either of the pipeline query options to the pipeline. I have other simple $match pipeline queries working.

```
cur, err := collection.Aggregate(ctx, pipeline)
if err != nil {
    return c.String(http.StatusNotFound, "No users found")
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the `subscriptions` field is optional in database, then if you want to filter documents with subscriptions, you have to filter by `subscriptions` being existent and its size greater than `0` (greater than zero condition is enough, as this can only be if the field exists). Similarly, if you want documents without subscriptions, you have to filter by it being non-existent or its size equal to `0`.

A simpler approach is test for the existance of the first array element. The first array element can only exist if `subscriptions` exists and its size is greater than `0`, and if the first element doesn't exist then `subscriptions` either does not exist or it's empty.

So simply use this:

```
pipeline = append(pipeline, bson.M{
    "$match": bson.M{
        "subscriptions.0": bson.M{"$exists": res},
    },
})
```

Comment: For checking if hasSubscriptions was false I tried: "$match": bson.M{"$or": []bson.M{{"subscriptions": nil}, {"$size": 0}}},  But it would not work, is there an issue with it? I will use your solution, but would like to know what it won't work, thank you

Comment: @John That filter would look like this: `"$match": bson.M{"$or": []interface{}{bson.M{"subscriptions": bson.M{"$exists": false}},bson.M{"subscriptions": bson.M{"$size": 0}}}}`